# If $ f \in \mathbb{Q}[x] $ is irreducible and has a root in $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) $, then it splits

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm trying to find a solution for the following problem:

let $ f \in \mathbb{Q}[x] $ be irreducible. Suppose $ f $ has a root in $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) $. Prove that $ \deg f \in \{1,2,4\} $ and that $ f $ splits into linear factors over $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) $.

It's easy to prove that the degree has to be either $ 1,2 $ or $ 4 $ (it has to divide $ 4 $ and can't be greater than $ 4 $). In the first two cases it obviously splits into linear factors. But I'm not sure why such polynomial of degree $ 4 $ has to split.

We can write $ f(x) = (x-a)p(x) $, where $ \deg p = 3 $ and $ a $ is the said root. How do I know that $ p $ has $ 3 $ roots?

I would appreciate some help with that.

Comment: Hint: Notice for $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$ the minimal polynomial which accept one of them as a root is of order 2, so if $f$ of order 4 and has a root in $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i) $ then as you wrote $ f(x) = (x-a)p(x) $  also you can show that $(x+a)| f(x)$. Hence this problem reduced to $deg(h)=2$  I hope this will help.
regrads

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any clean way of doing this without invoking Galois theory.  Essentially, the desired result follows from/is equivalent to the fact that the extension $\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{2})/\Bbb Q$ is Galois.

If you are familiar with the Galois group $G = \operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{2})/\Bbb Q)$, then it follows that if a root $a$ of $f(x)$ lies in $\Bbb Q(i, \sqrt{2})$, then $ga$ is also a root of $f(x)$ for any $g\in G$.  Moreover, the polynomial given by the product of the linear factors $\prod_{g\in G}(x-ga)$ has rational coefficients, so this equals $f(x)$ if you assume $f$ is monic irreducible of degree 4.

Doing this without the machinery of Galois theory is doable, but it looks to me to be somewhat onerous to do by hand.  Let your arbitrary root of your irreducible quartic $f(x)$ be $a= a_1$.  Write it in the form
$$
a_1 = A + Bi + C\sqrt{2} + Di\sqrt{2}
$$
 Then the other four roots of $f(x)$ are 
$$
a_2 = A - Bi + C\sqrt{2} - Di\sqrt{2}\\
a_3 = A + Bi - C\sqrt{2} - Di\sqrt{2}\\
a_4 = A - Bi - C\sqrt{2} + Di\sqrt{2}
$$
You can verify that $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)$ has rational coefficients by hand, which demonstrates that $f(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)$.  (These other $a_i$ values were obtained by using the Galois action on $a_1$, so you do need to know the Galois group to do this sort of thing in general.)

Answer (score 0):

The extension field $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ is the splitting field for the polynomial $(X^2-2)(X^2+1)$, so it is a Galois extension.

If $f$ has a root in a Galois extension, then it splits completely. Thus its splitting field is a subfield of $F$ and, by the dimension theorem, if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $\alpha\in F$ and we have $[F:\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]][\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, so the degree of $\alpha$ (and of $f$) is $1$, $2$ or $4$.